# How to clean code too much if else with enum

Tags: java, java-8, code-cleanup

I have the below code to write. It is taking one kind of enum type and return other enum value. How to remove the too much if else condition in the code and make it clean?

```java
private static QuestionType parseQuestionType(QuestionTypeInfo questionTypeInfo) {
        if (questionTypeInfo instanceof OpenEndedTextQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.OPEN_ENDED;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof MultiChoiceQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.MULTI_CHOICE;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof MatrixSinglePerRowQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.MATRIX_SINGLE_PER_ROW;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof OpenEndedTextQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.OPEN_ENDED;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof MatrixMultiPerRowQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.MATRIX_MULTI_PER_ROW;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof MatrixSideBySideQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.MATRIX_SIDE_BY_SIDE;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof MatrixSpreadSheetQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.MATRIX_SPREAD_SHEET;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof DataListQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.DATA_LIST;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof FileUploadQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.FILE_UPLOAD;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof InteractiveSlidingScaleQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.INTERACTIVE_SLIDING_SCALE;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof NetPromoterQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.NET_PROMOTER;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof RankOrderQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.RANK_ORDER;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof PresentationHeaderQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.PRESENTATION_HEADER;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof PresentationHtmlQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.PRESENTATION_HTML;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof AutoIncrementQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.AUTO_INCREMENT;
        } else if (questionTypeInfo instanceof SingleChoiceQuestionTypeInfo) {
            return QuestionType.SINGLE_CHOICE;
        }

        return null;
}
```

Comment: use a hasMap? with the one enum as key and the other as value?

Comment: Is it a 1:1 mapping?

Comment: At the very least use `switch case`

Comment: It's a code smell to use `instanceof`. Most of the time, it's better to have a method that the different classes implement specifically. (See Ondra's answer)

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `Map` as others suggested, but I personally would make use of delegation, if it makes sense in your case. In your `QuestionTypeInfo` interface, declare an abstract method `getQuestionType` that returns instance of the `QuestionType` enum, and override it in all of its implementations with proper value.

```java
interface QuestionTypeInfo {
    QuestionType getQuestionType();
}

enum OpenEndedTextQuestionTypeInfo implements QuestionTypeInfo {
    @Override
    public QuestionType getQuestionType() {
        return QuestionType.OPEN_ENDED;
    }
}
```

Then, in the `parseQuestionType` method, just use:

```java
private static QuestionType parseQuestionType(QuestionTypeInfo questionTypeInfo) {
        return questionTypeInfo.getQuestionType();
}
```

Comment: If this refactoring of the base interface is possible, then this is the way to go, every other solution just breaks OOP as one needs to know of every subtype of the base interface. This way the implementing class has to decide itself, what `QuestionType` it is. +1

Answer (score 2):

If **you** can guarantee, that these types are the only one that exists, and that there exist no other subclasses, you could create a mapping with the following signature:

```
Map<Class<? extends QuestionTypeInfo>, QuestionType> mapping;
```

And then establish the mappings. E.g. like this:

```
mapping.put(MatrixSinglePerRowQuestionTypeInfo.class, QuestionType.MATRIX_SINGLE_PER_ROW);
```

Then you can do a simple lookup like this:

```
return mapping.get(questionTypeInfo.getClass());
```

Though this only works when e.g. `MatrixSinglePerRowQuestionTypeInfo` is a class with no additional subclass. As the `Map` uses the `equals` method internally to check if the given key is existent. See this simplified example, which would break my proposed logic (**But will work with your existing one!!**):

```
// create a subclass
class SomeSubClass extends MatrixSinglePerRowQuestionTypeInfo { ... }

// initialize the mapping
mapping.put(MatrixSinglePerRowQuestionTypeInfo.class, Foo.BAR);

// in your lookup
mapping.get(MatrixSinglePerRowQuestionTypeInfo.class); // returns Foo.BAR as expected
mapping.get(SomeSubClass.class); // returns null??
```